# Font-face imported font not loading on webpage (django)

Tags: html, css, django, fonts, font-face

I've got a django web app running and am trying to upload a custom font. I'm using @font-face in the style sheet to grab the font files and then am using inline styling in the html template to apply the font (for some reason using body{} in the style sheet doesn't apply styles to the entire page).

@font-face code in style sheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'D3 Digitalism';
    src: local('D3 Digitalism') url('static/chatswap/font/d3-digitalism-font/D3Digitalism.woff2') format('woff2'),
    local('D3 Digitalism'), url('static/chatswap/font/d3-digitalism-font/D3Digitalism.woff') format('woff'),
    local('D3 Digitalism'), url('static/chatswap/font/d3-digitalism-font/D3Digitalism.eot'),
    local('D3 Digitalism'), url('static/chatswap/font/d3-digitalism-font/D3Digitalism.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

index.html template:

```
<body style="background-color: rgb(20,20,20); font-family: D3 Digitalism">
```

I've tried changing the name of the font in the CSS file to something without a number or space character in the name, did not help.

Comment: Did you check if the font is actually loaded properly in the devtools network tab?

Comment: When I take the local parameter out of the CSS then it gives me this error:     ``'chatswap/static/chatswap/font/d3-digitalism-font/D3Digitalism.woff2' could not be found``